# How do I setup boot server on Ubuntu to install an OS via LAN from ISO?

Tags: boot, server, system-installation, iso, lan

Just need some tips or directions, found too much info on the net.

Should I have specific `packages` installed?

What changes to what `files` are needed?

---

I already have `Apache2` server on the machine as PHP tools development server.

Would be great to not be limited to ISO image boot but also DOS apps.

Answer (score 1):

You found too much information because this is a complex issue.  You need to know a lot and read a lot about networking to accomplish this, but start with the official Ubuntu documentation on:

- [A disk-less workstation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto)

and then move on to:

- [PXE Boot Server Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallServer)

and finally (if needed)

- [PXE boot multiple distributions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallMultiDistro)

Just to re-iterate: you need to know what Wake-On-LAN is, TFTP (which is not the same as FTP) and PXE before even starting.

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask